# Idea's to Create a table dynamically

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-tables

Is it possible to create a table in SQL dynamically. In my web application I need to store the  data in a table named as **"INFO_2013"** for this year (i.e) 2013. When the system date changes to 2014, then a new table has to be created as **"INFO_2014"** and the values have to be added in that table.

NOTE : Also the Table has to be in the same DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid using this approach.

Why not rather create a single table, with a `YEAR` column, which will identify which year it is from?

Further to that, if you are woried about the table getting to large, you might want to take a look at [Creating Partitioned Tables and Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

May have a look at these too

[Index Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Types of Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175049%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Ya @astander ! it's a better approach. But the main thing is I need to insert 50 records daily...In this case for 1 month I have to update nearly 1500 records. what happens for 1 year. If I stores value for nearly 5 years, then what happens ??? That's why am looking for the solution....

Comment: It could be even simpler.  If the table has any date or datetime fields, they can be used to determine the year.

Comment: @Elango_Thanumalayan, you are describing a very small database.  Plus, it's the same number of records no matter how many tables you have.  astander's approach makes life so much easier than what you are contemplating.

Comment: 18,250 records a year is really very small. Even when you look at 10 years worth of data, a simple index will be sufficient.

Comment: Thankx @astander am really looking for the reference you have given.. I will gatback soon. anyway thnkx for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000) 
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(100)

SET @table = 'INFO_2013'

SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE '+@table+'
(
RollNumber INT
,Name VARCHAR(50)
)'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

Comment: While this answer fulfills the OP's question, [astander's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16337602/745511) is a better practice.

Comment: @Anu, Can you explain me these queries.

Comment: This is very simple, I have created string with Create table command and after that I have executed it.
Tell me, In which part you have query. Thanks.

Comment: @Anu, What for Declare SQL , Declare table are given...? what is the use of it ? (Plz, notify me by @my_name)

Comment: @Elango_Thanumalayan , this is not table , this is simple variable which hold string.

Comment: OK... I got it  @Anu. Thnkx for your support.